# Parsing curl json output using awk

Tags: json, shell, csv, curl, awk

Using this command in a loop:

```
curl -s -X POST -F "filedata=@inputfile" -F "containerid=documentLibrary" -F "destination=filelocation" http://user:pass@server:host/service/api/upload;
```

I am able to get the following:

> ```
> {
>    "nodeRef": "123",
>    "fileName": "filename.pdf",
>    "status":
>    {
>       "code": 200,
>       "name": "OK",
>       "description": "File uploaded successfully"
>    }
> }
> ```

this snippet will appear 100s, 1000s of times. I need to extract just the nodeRef value (123) and put into a csv using awk or any other parsing tool that does not require installation like jq.

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my Posts / Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Why not install `jq`? That's a tool that is designed to do exactly the job you want.  Trying to muck around with `awk` or similar tools that weren't design for JSON is going to be fragile at best.

Comment: If your system has `python` installed then you have a native JSON parsing library available (the `json` module) AND a CSV reading/writing module (`csv`).  So you could use that as the basis for a more robust solution.

Comment: avoiding jq installation is wrong way to go ... This will inevitably come into trouble some day ...

Answer (score 0):

lacking specialized json tools, perhaps `grep`

```
... | grep -oP '(?<="nodeRef": ")\w+'
```

still assumes something about the format...

Answer (score 0):

Few `awk` approach:-

```
<curl command> | awk -F'"' '/nodeRef/{ print $(NF-1) }' 

<curl command> | awk '/nodeRef/{X=$NF;gsub(/[",]/,Y,X);print X}'
```